# Virtualenv error while setting up Django in Azure Cloud Platform on Mac

Tags: python, django, azure, virtualenv

I found the tutorial here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/

I am trying to create a Django project and sychronize it with Github and azure cloud platform. As for the prerequisites, I have everything except Python Tools for Visual Studio because I use PyCharm for development.

I cloned the repository as the tutorial indicates, but when I try to create a virtual environment

**$ python -m virtualenv env**

I get the following response:

```
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/dimitris/JBring/env/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dimitris/JBring/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/dimitris/JBring/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/dimitris/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/dimitris/JBring/env/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I am using Python 2.7 that is installed with the anaconda package. I installed virtualenv using:

**`conda install virtualenv`**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue using `conda`. It seems that `conda` configured the  `~/.bash_profile` to muck with the `PYTHONPATH`. You can try to check the `PYTHONPATH` via the code below in the Python interpreter.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

The default Python packages installed by OS at the paths `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` & `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, but `conda` installed python packages at the path `~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-package` and configured the `~/.bash_profile` to set the local `PYTHONPATH`(not global, don't need `sudo`).

To resolve the issue, try to use the command `virtual env --no-setuptools --no-pip --no-wheel`.

Comment: If it's created without Setup tools, how can I then install packages within environment?